# Count number of rows where Extract Value found a match

Tags: mysql, xml, xpath, extract-value

100,000 rows in a table which contains a column that stores a large XML block, I need to check if there is a certain XML tag is filled with data in this column, lets say the column is called test_request and the XML tag is named 'd'. Also I want to make sure that the value inside 'd' doesn't contain a newline /n within the XML tag. So for every row that has a match I want to add 1 to a overall count. Here is my query so far.

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE( UNCOMPRESS(`test__request` ) ,  count('/a/b/c/d') ) 
FROM testTable16
WHERE  `test_created` >  '2014-08-16 10:00:00'
AND  `test_created` <=  '2014-08-16 10:10:00'
AND  `test_client` =  'test2'
AND  `test_user` =  'testuser2'
AND UNCOMPRESS(  `test__request` ) LIKE  '%<testID>test</testID>%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

it doesn't work though as it returns 100,000 rows which I cant obviously sift through. And I am not sure how to do the isnt newline check.

Comment: is this mysql or sql?

Comment: mysql, sorry stackoverflow told me it was a good idea to add SQL as a tag.

Comment: just as a good rule of thumb keep your tags as specific as possible.. mysql doesn't support everything sql does so it needs to be clarified :)

Comment: what comes out from your extractvalue() select? can we see some data? :)

Comment: The returned is the first 30 rows contains 0 (the rest could contain either 0 or 1, the point is I cant search all the rows there are too many which is why I need a total of matches)

Comment: If I put in a Xpath of a tag I know thats always there the rows return a 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only to return rows with a count, you should move your count to the `WHERE` clause.

My XPATH is a little rusty, but I believe you can use a predicate with the contains function:

```
SELECT *
FROM testTable16
WHERE  `test_created` >  '2014-08-16 10:00:00'
AND  `test_created` <=  '2014-08-16 10:10:00'
AND  `test_client` =  'test2'
AND  `test_user` =  'testuser2'
AND UNCOMPRESS(`test__request`) LIKE  '%<testID>test</testID>%'
AND EXTRACTVALUE( 
      UNCOMPRESS(`test__request`),  
      'count(/a/b/c/d[contains(text(),"\n")])'
    ) > 0
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

If you want to return a count of all rows that have at least one match use `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`

If you want a total of all the node counts use:

```
SELECT SUM(EXTRACTVALUE( 
         UNCOMPRESS(`test__request`),  
         'count(/a/b/c/d[contains(text(),"\n")])'
       ))
FROM testTable16
WHERE  `test_created` >  '2014-08-16 10:00:00'
AND  `test_created` <=  '2014-08-16 10:10:00'
AND  `test_client` =  'test2'
AND  `test_user` =  'testuser2'
AND UNCOMPRESS(`test__request`) LIKE '%<testID>test</testID>%'
```

Comment: I am getting invalid use of group function.

Comment: @MatthewUnderwood Oh sorry, the count needs to be within the XPATH.. i'll update.

Comment: I think that has worked, the count goes down when I add more tags, which is what I was expecting, what I will do is put a limit 30 and check the XML data coming back. Then I will up vote you and mark you as correct. Wont be long.

Comment: Cool, happy to help.. count goes down when you add more tags? do you mean to the `WHERE` conditions/XPATH conditions? If you mean to the XML the count should only go up! Bear in mind the `LIMIT` is applied last, so it won't affect a MySQL aggregate `COUNT(*)` or `SUM(...)`.

Comment: Yeah I was refering to the WHERE, all the rows should contain tag a and b but c and d can be optional (its specific to my work). Hence I expect there to be a lower count number when a/d/c rather then a/b.

Comment: Thanks man, note that that solution may not be optimal performance-wise!